# React Native Firebase offline writes + updates not syncing when online

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I work on a bare react-native project where I have to use Firebase persistence. I use react-native-firebase package to do all my request.

When I write offline with react-native-firebase/firestore and then go online, it syncs with backOffice.

```
firestore().collection(col).add(data)
```

When I update data with react-native-firebase/firestore and then go online, it sync with backOffice.

```
firestore().collection(col).doc(id).update(data)
```

But when I write offline and then update this new data (offline), when I go online the data disappears, like the pending requests are not syncing.

Any idea why?

Comment: in firestore when you update the same documents many times, only the last update get sync with the database. So what I guess here is that you updated your documents with some empty data in one last update and that one is the one that was synced to the database. **does the document exist with empty data or it's not there at all?**

Comment: Yes the document exist thanks! The problem was that à field with the serverTimestamp() value was set to null when return online (logic)

Answer (score 2):

serverTimestamp is quite complex topic in relation to firestore but the main point is that **serverTimestamp** value is never set on the client side and it's always **null**  however it will be set only on the server. you can get this value by:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

your code to set it should be somthing like:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const ref = firestore.collection('messages').doc('foo')
ref.set({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

to have a deeper understanding on this, check out this [detailed article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b) by a firebase expert

Answer (score 0):

So, when you write data offline using `firestore().collection(col).add(data)` and then updating this new data while still offline, it's possible that the pending request for the update is not syncing properly when you go back online.

Now, this can happen due to the order of operations and how Firebase handles offline updates. In some cases, the update request might get processed before the initial write request, which leads to unexpected behaviour. To ensure consistent synchronisation, you can try to handle data updates more explicitly in your code.

I’ve applied something like this in one of my projects. Here is the overall code:

```js
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// Define your collection and document references
const collectionRef = firestore().collection('yourCollection');
const documentRef = collectionRef.doc('yourDocumentId');

// Define the data you want to update
const updateData = {
  fieldToUpdate: 'UpdatedValue',
};

// Check network connectivity (optional)
const isConnected = /* logic to check network connectivity */;

// Function to update data
const updateDataInFirestore = async () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    // If online, update the data directly in Firestore
    await documentRef.update(updateData);
  } else {
    // If offline, update the data locally
    // You can maintain a local copy of the data and apply the update
    const currentData = /* retrieve the current data locally */;
    const updatedData = { ...currentData, ...updateData };

    // Store the updated data locally for later synchronization
    /* logic to store updatedData locally */
  }
};

// Later, when you're back online, you can synchronize the updated data
const synchronizeData = async () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    // Retrieve the locally updated data
    const locallyUpdatedData = /* retrieve locally updated data */;

    // Update the data in Firestore to reflect the local changes
    await documentRef.set(locallyUpdatedData, { merge: true });
  }
};

// Call the update function when needed
updateDataInFirestore();

// Call the synchronization function when you're back online
synchronizeData();
```

Now here I  first checked the network connectivity and then explicitly handled the data updates based on whether the app is online or offline. When online, the data is updated directly in Firestore, and when offline, the update is applied locally, and the changes are stored for later synchronization when you regain connectivity. The synchronizeData function handles the synchronization process.

Comment: Please note that explicit affiliation is **required** whenever sharing links to sites or products where you are affiliated.

Comment: Also, if you're not sure whether an article can help the reader, why share it in the first place?